# Cuenta los puntos de una función

Tags: javascript

Necesito una ayuda para ver en que parte he fallado con el código que he escrito ya que no funciona. Preciso de una función que reciba una cadena `str` y retorne el número de puntos (`.`) que hay en `str`.

Este es el código que he escrito pero no funciona:

```js
function contarPuntos(palabra) {
  let soloPuntos = palabra;
  let contador = 0
  for(i=0; i<soloPuntos.length; i++) {
    if(soloPuntos[i] === ".") {
      contador++;
    }
  }
  console.log(soloPuntos);
  return contador
}


console.log(contarPuntos("C.O.D.E"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: A mi sí que me funciona... me cuenta 3: https://jsfiddle.net/ts03d5fk/

Comment: Tu función realiza lo que pides, al menos con la cadena del ejemplo. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: En este momento estoy usando la consola de FREECODECAMP . https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/comment-your-javascript-code            
Acabo de ejecutar el codigo en stackoverflow y si funciona. Alguien puede podria decirme poqrue en la consola de stackoverflow si funciona y en la consola de la otra pagina web no funciona ? gracias

Comment: Porque seguramente dicha consola utiliza el token `"use strict";`. El error que te lanza es: `ReferenceError: i is not defined`. En el bucle `for` cambia la declaración de `i=0` por `let i = 0`, y te funcionará. Saludos

Comment: Por cierto, si bien tu función es correcta, podrías evitar el bucle `for` si usas simplemente métodos de Arrray, por ejemplo, dentro de tu función podrías implementar una sola linea: `return palabra.split('.').length - 1;` Con eso obtienes la cantidad de caracteres `.` dentro de la palabra. Saludos

Comment: Si añades el mensaje de error que te da la consola de FreeCodeCamp: `ReferenceError: i is not defined`, tanto al título de la pregunta como a la pregunta misma, se puede redactar una respuesta que ayude a otros usuarios. Saludos

Comment: disculpa los pocos conocimientos que tengo. La situacion es que recien llevo 1 semana viendo videos de youtube sobre Aprende javascript desde Cero. Todavia no he recibido clases de como usar la sentencia "split"